# What does [1] mean when we put it in the end of a function and in the end of a tuple?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, linked-list

I am studying other people's code, and part of the code confuses me a lot. What does `[1]` mean in the `remove(head)[1]`? Also, what is `(head, head.next)[i+1 == n]`? Could someone help me?

In the code, `head` is the head of a linked list, coming from another Class called ListNode, and it contains two functions. One is `head.val`, which shows the value of head. Another one is `head.next`, which calls the next object in the linked list. Here `n` is an int. This code tries to remove the Nth node from the end of list and return its head.

For example,

Given linked list: 1->2->3->4->5, and n = 2.

After removing the second node from the end, the linked list becomes 1->2->3->5.

Following is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head, n):
        def remove(head):
            if not head:
                return 0, head
            i, head.next = remove(head.next)
            return i+1, (head, head.next)[i+1 == n]
        return remove(head)[1]
```

Comment: What does it do when it's not placed at the end of a function. What does `i+1 == n` evaluate to? What does `int(True)` or `int(False)` evaluate to? If you can answer all of those, you've solved your question.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I edited the post. Hope this time it is clear.

Comment: The question is clear. But the answer is also clear. And I'm asking you so you can think about what the code does: what does `[]` do, for example, when called on a list? What does `int(True)` do? If you know that, you can understand the code.

Comment: look   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422228/square-brackets-after-a-function-call this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function remove returns a tuple(actually a pair) - first value being index and the second value being the removed element. So try to solve your question one step at a time. Replace the call to the function by the value it returns and see if now the square brackets make sense.